# Laravel 5 check if current url matches action

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am currently generating my application urls using `{{action('Namespace\Class@method')}}`. How would I check if the current page request maps to that current action `Namespace\Class@method`?

I would like to do something like:

```
<a href="{{action('Namespace\Class@method')}}
  @if (currentAction('Namespace\Class@method'))
    class="active"
  @endif
>Some link</a>
```

How would I achieve this in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 9):

There's no built in method for this, however you can retrieve the current action name with `Route::currentRouteAction()`. Unfortunately this method will return a fully namespaced class name. So you will get something like:

```
App\Http\Controllers\FooBarController@method
```

You can either check for that or use something like `ends_with` so you don't have to specify the full path:

```
@if(ends_with(Route::currentRouteAction(), 'FooBarController@method'))
```

---

You might also consider *naming* your routes with `'as' => 'route.name'`. This would allow you to use: `Route::is('route.name')`

Comment: Thank you for including the bit about naming your routes. I already had mine named so that saved me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 9):

Actualy I had it simplified to the following code:

```
 <li class="@if(Route::is('getLogin')) active @endif"><a href="{{URL::route('getLogin')}}">Login</a></li>
```

That assumes that you have named routes. Which is a good idea in the first place, because you migth change the url of an action without going through your whole project to change the links to that action.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but for what it is worth.

Laravel has a couple of [built-in helper methods for referring to URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#urls) action and route.

---

**`action`**

Your route file would look like this.

```
Route::get('/funtastic', 'FuntasticController@show');
```

Your blade view would look like this

```
<a href="{{action('FuntasticController@show')}}
  @if(action('FuntasticController@show') == Request::url())  
    class="active"
  @endif
>Some link</a>
```

---

**`route`**

If you use [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes).

```
<a href="{{route('namedRoute')}}
  @if(route('namedRoute') == Request::url()) 
    class="active"
  @endif
>Some link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it without any named routes

```
<a class="{{ str_contains(request()->url(), '/some-page') ? 'active' : '' }}" href="/some-page">Some Page</a>
```

This is not a perfect solution but it works for most cases

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me.

```
<a class="@if (\Route::current()->getName() == 'device_media') active @endif" href="{{ route('device_media', ['brand_slug'=>$brand->slug, 'slug'=>$device->slug]) }}" > Media</a>
```